# Why ipv6 stack (on linux) can interpret ipv4 adresses?

Tags: linux, ipv6, ipv4

I thought that dual stack ipv4 / ipv6 was necessary, nginx, apache, ssh listen both on ipv4 and ipv6 interfaces.
But after using tvheadend, i see that even if it listens only on the ipv6 stack, it responds to ipv4 adresses too ... why ?
here is the proof :

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n

tvheadend 3676  hts   33u  IPv6 679854      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.8:9981->192.168.0.4:57868 (ESTABLISHED)
```

The ipv6 stack uses 192.168.x.x ipv4 adresses...

And there is no listening on ipv4 :

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN | grep tvheadend

tvheadend 3676  hts    7u  IPv6 439770      0t0  TCP *:9981 (LISTEN)

tvheadend 3676  hts    8u  IPv6 439773      0t0  TCP *:9982 (LISTEN)


sudo netstat -tlnp | grep tvheadend

tcp6       0      0 :::9981                   :::*                    LISTEN      3676/tvheadend
tcp6       0      0 :::9982                   :::*                    LISTEN      3676/tvheadend
```

Comment: What would `netstat -tlnp | grep tvheadend` output?

Comment: Comments are bad for multiline output. Please try to edit your question instead.

Comment: `lsof` output `TCP *:9981 (LISTEN)` shows it is listening on all interfaces as is `netstat` with `:::9981`

Answer (score 1):

If IPv4 and IPv6 stacks are working and only an IPv6 listener exists, it is normal to send to v6 and just map v4 sender addresses to ipv6 by default on many (if not all major) OSes such as Linux. The `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option can be used on most OSes, to disable this as found in [this documentation](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/ch23s01.html#1.3.1).

Comment: great answer, thank you, i have seen on the tvheadend web interface a "::ffff:192.168.0.x" style address of a client connected but,even if it looked strange, i didn't google it cause I had other problems with tvheadend at this moment. thx for your explaination : it is IPv4 Mapped Addresses... didn't know them...

Comment: @shrd happy to help, To avoid getting closed on future questions like this one, I guess you would technically have to add a test server to make it purely on topic or maybe use socat for the example server to make it sort of a scripting question..